# Multicollinearity with interaction term and fixed effects

Tags: econometrics, applied-econometrics, r

I have the following regression including an interaction term and fixed effects

```
feols(work ~ i(age_cohort, log(tot_bomb_per)) + yrschool + nchild + married + as.factor(minority) | geo1_vn1989 + age_cohort,
            subset(phc89, female == 1 & birthyr > 1925 & birthyr < 1974 & migration == 0),
            weights = ~perwt,
            vcov = ~geo1_vn1989)
```

`age_cohort` is the age cohort of individual i, `tot_bomb_per` is the province-level bombing intensity of province p, `geo1_vn1989` are province fixed effects and `age_cohort` are age cohort fixed effects.

After running that code, I am getting this message

```
The variable 'age_cohort::61-65:log(tot_bomb_per)' has been removed because of collinearity (see $collin.var).
```

Can you please help me explain why I have encountered this error message, and if I should remove the fixed effects. Thank you.